WKWebView OAuth popup misses window.opener in iOS 17.5+
In my project, I'm using the WKWebView to display the Google OAuth popup. After it appears, the JS window.opener is null, and because of that, the original window cannot receive an auth token in a callback. This works perfectly fine in iOS 17.0 and earlier, but broken starting from 17.5. I've tested on the 18.0 too - same results the opener is always null no matter what I try.
HTML Part:
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var global = {};

    window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
        console.log("Trying to catch Google OAuth");
        console.log(event);
    });

    function client() {
        if (global.client === undefined) {
            global.client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
                client_id: '<client_id>',
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email \
                    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
                callback: function (responseToken) {
                    console.log("=== Callback ===");
                    console.log(responseToken);
                    let auth = document.getElementById("auth");
                    auth.textContent = 'Token: ' + responseToken.access_token
                }
            });
        }
        return global.client;
    }

    function googleOauthClient() {
        console.log("Trying to login");
        let auth = document.getElementById("auth");
        auth.textContent = 'In Progress...';
        client().requestAccessToken();
    }
</script>
<body>
<div id="center">
    <a onclick="googleOauthClient()"><h1>Google Login Attempt</h1></a>
    <h2 id="auth"></h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>

In iOS showing popup is implemented as:
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "SafariServices/SafariServices.h"

@interface WebViewController () <WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate> {
    WKWebView *web;
    WKWebView *popupWebView;
}
@end

@implementation WebViewController

- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    
    WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    [[config preferences] setJavaScriptEnabled:YES];
    [[config preferences] setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically:NO];
    [[config defaultWebpagePreferences] setAllowsContentJavaScript:YES];
    [config setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
    
    web = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:config];
    [web setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [web setAllowsLinkPreview:YES];
    [web setNavigationDelegate:self];
    [web setUIDelegate:self];
    [web setInspectable:YES];
    [web setCustomUserAgent:[[web valueForKey:@"userAgent"] stringByAppendingString:@" Safari"]];
    
    [[self view] addSubview:web];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *url = @"http://localhost:8080/oauth"; // A simple Spring Boot App where HTML is hosted
    [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction
decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}

- (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures {
    
    if (navigationAction.targetFrame == nil) {
        popupWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webView.frame configuration:configuration];
        [popupWebView setCustomUserAgent: [webView customUserAgent]];
        [popupWebView setUIDelegate:self];
        [popupWebView setNavigationDelegate:self];
        [popupWebView setInspectable:true];
        [[[popupWebView configuration] defaultWebpagePreferences] setAllowsContentJavaScript:YES];
        
        [[[popupWebView configuration] preferences] setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically:NO];
        [[[popupWebView configuration] preferences] setJavaScriptEnabled:YES];
        [[popupWebView configuration] setSuppressesIncrementalRendering:YES];
            
        [webView addSubview:popupWebView];
        [popupWebView loadRequest:[navigationAction.request copy]];

        return popupWebView;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)webViewDidClose:(WKWebView *)webView {
        [webView removeFromSuperview];
        popupWebView = nil;
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFailProvisionalNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation withError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailProvisionalNavigation: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFailNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation withError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailNavigation: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView requestMediaCapturePermissionForOrigin:(WKSecurityOrigin *)origin initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame
           type:(WKMediaCaptureType)type decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKPermissionDecision decision))decisionHandler {
    decisionHandler(WKPermissionDecisionGrant);
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView requestDeviceOrientationAndMotionPermissionForOrigin:(WKSecurityOrigin *)origin
initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKPermissionDecision decision))decisionHandler {
    decisionHandler(WKPermissionDecisionGrant);
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runOpenPanelWithParameters:(WKOpenPanelParameters *)parameters
initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<NSURL *> * _Nullable URLs))completionHandler {
    completionHandler(nil);
}
@end

This works in the SFSafariViewController, but I cannot use it because I need to hide the Navigation and Status bar panels.
What else I've tried so far:

Disabled in the Settings -> Safari -> Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy, Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy and Disable Removal of 3rd-Party Cookie Blocking (ITP);
Disabled Popup Blocking;
Added NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Info.plist (added all possible security policies too);
Added NSCrossWebsiteTrackingUsageDescription to Info.plist, and after enabled Allow Cross-Website Tracking in the App Settings;

And ideas about what I might be doing wrong? Or maybe some workaround I can utilize to get the Google OAuth token from the popup. Thanks in advance.

I am running into something similar with a webapp running in Safari (no WKWebVIew involved). window.opener ends up being null after I open a popup to the google oauth2 endpoint and it redirects back to my app. Only happens on iPad with iOS 18. iPhone with iOS 18 works. iPad with iOS 17.2 works.
One potential clue is if I go to Settings => Apps => Safari => Advanced => Feature Flags and turn off "swap processes on cross-site navigation" then the problem goes away.
